# Epson L365 Scanner UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scanner, epson

I have installed an L365 EPSON printer/scanner using the drivers provided on the epson site (http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule). Used the ./install.sh command. 
Printer is working OK, scanner otherwise opens, when I click update, it does the pre scan (it shows the pre scan image).When I ask to scan, it asks for the file name and location to save, the scanner works, but the file is not saved at all. (scans but do not save).
what can it be?

Comment: Make sure you're selecting a locating for the saved file where your user has writing permissions.

Comment: Doing it as root, and tried several locations already.

Comment: As root is a big mistake.